# How do I modify the boot configuration to make it compatible by default?

Tags: boot, acer, compatibility

I have an acer cloudbook 14 and it was a terrible windows machine. the hd is only 32g so it only had about 8gb free after updates if that. after enough messing around I found out I can get mint to boot and install if I enter "edd=off noapic" at the end of the linux /vmlinuz-linux... bootline. I'm asking how to make it boot this way by default because this computer is for my mom and little brother and nobody is going to want to add that line every time just to get it to boot properly. these new laptops don't seem to be very  compatible and I feel like they used to be a little more user friendly when it came to installation.

Answer (score 0):

Using any editor, open `/etc/default/grub`

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Add in your options

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash edd=off noapic"
```

Save the file and update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```